# How to add get method to link that I am echoing from php

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a simple form when I submit it checks if number exist in database and then it echoes one of two links depending if the condition is satisfied. Now I want him to echo and that number (correct one that exist in database) to the end of the link. How could i do that? For example this is number I get from form

```
$example = $_POST['example'];
```

and after a condition I have this

```
echo "<script>window.location = 'www.examplelink.com/something';</script>";
```

I presume it would go like this

```
echo "<script>window.location = 'www.examplelink.com/something example=".$example."';</script>";
```

But it's not working

Comment: You're redirecting (via JS) after submission. How exactly do you want to 'show' the value? If you want to show it... why redirect??

Comment: does that number is going to be a part of url ??

Comment: what do you mean, not workin? Are you sure, is there anything in your `$_POST['example']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the `GET` method is a reference to the search parameters on a URL.  At the end of your URL, simply define the search parameters by adding a **'?'** then `example=...`

This can be followed up with an ampersand to distinguish between different search variables.

```
echo "<script>window.location = 'www.examplelink.com/something.php?example=".$example."';</script>";
```

If you use this then you must call the `$_GET['example']` variable when PHP reloads the page.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just redirect the user using PHP?

```
if ( $variable1 == $variable2 ) {
    header("Location: http://www.examplelink.com/somethingexample=" . $example );
}
```

or even:

```
if ( $variable1 == $variable2 ) {
    header("Location: http://www.examplelink.com/somethingexample=" . $_POST['example'] );
}
```